# Making a D3 bar chart sorted by JSON string?

Tags: json, d3.js

I am working on making a D3 bar graph that shows weight output by location using a JSON file. There is one JSON file I am reading in that includes many entries of data that are added to the JSON file throughout the day. Each entry within the JSON file includes an ID, weight, location, and other irrelevant information. Here is the basic format format of the JSON file:

```
[{"id":1,"weight":51.2,"location":"Airport", ...},{"id":2,"weight":89.2,"location":"Uptown", ...},{"id":3,"weight":31.8,"location":"Airport", ...}, ....,{"id":90,"weight":96.8,"location":"Monroe", ...}]
```

I understand how to make a bar chart perfectly fine, my problem is stacking the weight for each location so that each location is shown on the X axis only once, and the total weight for each location is shown as the length of the corresponding bar. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you saying you want a stack bar chart for location  like this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need to prepare your data then. Walk through it and summarize all values corresponding to every distinct location.

It could be performed by `d3` own methods or some third-party library like `lodash` or `underscore`.

```js
var data = [
    {"id":1,"weight":51.2,"location":"Airport"},
    {"id":2,"weight":89.2,"location":"Uptown"},
    {"id":3,"weight":31.8,"location":"Airport"},
    {"id":90,"weight":96.8,"location":"Monroe"}
];

function handleWithD3(dataload) {
  /* group data be value of 'location' field */
  var d3grouped = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.location;})
    .entries(data);

  /* create new array with items extended with 'sum' value */
  var result = d3grouped.map(function(item) {
    /* calculate sum of weights for every item in array */
    item.sum = d3.sum(item.values, function(d) { return d.weight; });
    return item;
  });

  return result;
}

function handleWithUnderscore(dataload) {
  var _grouped = _.groupBy(data, function (item) { return item.location; });

  var result = _.map(_grouped, function(dataBlock, key, list) {
    return {
      key: key,
      values: dataBlock,
      sum: _.reduce(_.pluck(dataBlock, 'weight'), function(prev, next) { return prev + next; }, 0)
    };
  });

  return result;
}

document.getElementById('d3').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(handleWithD3(data));
document.getElementById('underscore').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(handleWithUnderscore(data));
```

```css
#d3 {
  color: blue;
}
#underscore {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="d3"></div>
<div id="underscore"></div>
```